# Rails 3.2 basic relationship has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've reread the rails guide to associations but still am hitting my head up against the wall. I've seen some advanced questions on Stack Overflow and am not able to determine if they shed light on my problem. Perhaps I've haven't gotten my mind wrapped around this. Please show me what I'm not seeing.

I have a School.rb which has_many Events, has_many Venues. Each of the Events and Venues belongs_to School. I'm trying to link up the Venue to an Event. They are tied to the school because they have a matching school_id. The name of the school is easily applied in Event#show and Venue#show as expected. The trick is how do I craft the Event controller to use the school_id to pull the Venue's addy in the Event#show page?

My attempts keep missing so I got to thinking maybe I have to make the Event belongs_to Venue and Venue has_many Events. Is that the right thing to do?

I attempt  <%= @event.venue.address %> but that fails with 'undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass'

Maybe I'm overthinking it but as I mention above, I don't know enough to ask the right question. If I was to put my query in English terms it would be "Grab the instance of Venue whose school_id matches the school_id of the current/active Event." Does that make sense? I've attempted to find something close to that in the rails guides and attempted this:

```
 @venues = Venue.where(:school_id => @school_id)
```

undefined method `address' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation. The venue address is in the venue model.

Here's my school.rb:

```
 class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy   
 has_many :venues, :dependent => :destroy
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :event   belongs_to :venue
  def self.fetch_for_name(_name)
 school = self.new(:name => _name)
  end 
 end
```

Here's my event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

resourcify
belongs_to :school
 belongs_to :venue
 end
```

Here's my Venue.rb:

```
 class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base

  resourcify
  belongs_to :school
   has_many :events

   end
```

Please help me get over this baby step, sam

Comment: Could you post your actual active record relationships? It'll make everything a million times easier

Comment: I edited my answer to more directly answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)  part of the guide and ensure you have has_many through relationship between venue and events here as explained in the link...

Answer (score 0):

To do the exact thing you are asking, you'd create a method in Venue to query for a given event.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :events
  def self.venue_for_event(event)
    where("school_id = ?", event.school_id)
  end
end
```

However, there are some questions to be asked about your models. Why does a school have many events and venues yet also belong to one event and venue? What is the problem you are trying to solve with these models? If school is the glue that holds venues and events together, than consider making it a join model in a `has_many, :through` relationshuip

Comment: There is no reason that the school belongs_to event and venue is to ensure that I can exploit the data reciprocally, mainly due to my inexperience. The problem is that I want to have the school be the unifier between its events, venues. And for data in venues, like an addy, to appear in a shool's events. I want to understand how I can go a level deeper.

Comment: Thx. I've altered school.rb to has_many :venues, :through => :events. I'm unsure how to use venue_for_event in a controller and how it would show up in event#show? Following the rails guide (physician.patients = patients) I tried: school.events = events but that failed. I want to know how the language interacts model/controller/views and get stumped on the basics.